# "Show table" equivalent syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need to do the equivalent of

```
SHOW TABLES LIKE 'ka_product_import'
```

in SQL Server 2008. How can I do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp  
Please read the manuals/tutorials first

Comment: @OP I've tried to clarify your question - please do tell me I've got the intended meaning wrong!

Comment: Why the downvotes?  It's not his fault he doesn't know.  I came here looking for the answer, and I'm glad he asked the question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding are you trying to show all tables with the name `KA_PRODUCT_IMPORT`:

```
SELECT * FROM
SYS.TABLES
WHERE NAME LIKE '%KA_PRODUCT_IMPORT%'
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all you guys that help me to find an answer :)
Im a little noob haha so I'll try to do it better the next time.. 

:)